# Getting error in FeatureBackground() method while running specflow scenario

Tags: c#, .net, specflow

I am running the automation using the specflow, however when I try to run a specific scenario from VS,I am getting below errors::
Result StackTrace:
at Sample.Test.Automation.Stories.BookingFeature.FeatureBackground() in 
C:\Git\em\FunctionalAutomation\AutomationTests\NonUI\Sample.Test.Automation.Stories\Booking.feature:line 9

TestCleanup Stack Trace
   at Sample.Test.Automation.Stories.BookingFeature.ScenarioTearDown()
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
TestCleanup method Sample.Test.Automation.Stories.BookingFeature.ScenarioTearDown threw exception. System.NullReferenceException: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

I think it has something to do with the dll is not being loaded or something but I am unable to get the error. 
I tried putting the try catch block in the FeatureBackground() method in the .feature.cs file but it does not throw any exception in the try catch block.

Comment: Could you add the background, the used bindings and possible hooks? Without code it is hard to see the Null Reference

Comment: "@PQSM"
"@nanderie"
Feature: Booking
As the Booking User
I Want To ensure that the booking is eligible for the relevant jurisdiction 
So That I can maintain correct requirements

Background:
    Given I have active entities in Booking mapped as follows 
 | EasyIdentifier | 
 | PR1            | 
 | PR2            | 
 | PR3            | 
  And following gadget exists in system
  
"@PQSM"
"@PQSM-1983-AcceptanceCriteria1"
Scenario Outline: Post-Reg Assets associated with in-scope regulators
Given I have an Asset with PrePost Reg Arrangement flag set to "Post"